# Python Error: Could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, pca

While trying to write my own PCA, I need to calculate the matrix X*X.T
And I write the following code:
  m_PCA1 = m_PCA.dot(m_PCA_T)
And get an error: [Could not be broadcast together with shapes (22,818) and (18,818)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok3VT.png)
Then I change it to outer product:
  m_PCA1 = np.outer(m_PCA,m_PCA)
And still get an error
[Could not be broadcast together with shapes (22,818) and (18,818)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8SmY.png)

I wonder why a vector cannot dot its transpose or cross itself, and it's strange that inside outer function I write two same variable but the shape are different

Comment: Please stop posting screenshots. There's no reason that you couldn't post the error as formatted text. Please give a [mcve]. Why was this upvoted?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow @Yang Yuhan ! You can use triple-backticks ``` ``` to format your code, like this: ```import pca``` . If you format your code nicely in your post, more people will want to take a look and help. Again welcome to SO :)

Comment: You should probably have a numpy tag, since the question is about errors involving numpy objects and functions.  Also consider dropping the PCA tag, or if you think it's important, clarify in text which PCA you mean (probably "principal component analysis") and why it's an issue. 
To answer your question, also look at (and reference in your post), documentation at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_dot.htm and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html
Verify your matrices have appropriate types & shapes. Include your verification steps in the post